# Using jQuery Switch Case to Change text Color

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

The following script achieves my goal of changing the colors of contained words found in my anchor tags, however I would like to make my script more elegant. How can I write the following script using a switch case statement in jQuery?

```
//change color of categories
    jQuery("a:contains('Strawberries')").css("color","#34a07e");

    jQuery("a:contains('Apples')").css("color","#3194b1");

    jQuery("a:contains('Peaches')").css("color","#e1a82a");

    jQuery("a:contains('Bananas')").css("color","#ff0b00");
```

HTML:

```
<a title="Fruits in basket Strawberries" href="#">Strawberries</a>

<a title="Fruits in basket Apples" href="#">Apples</a>

<a title="Fruits in basket Peaches" href="#">Peaches</a>

<a title="Fruits in basket Bananas" href="#">Bananas</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I didn't use a switch/case, but here's a more elegant way of doing what you want.  Click the button below to run and view the results.

1. Create an object mapping the text name to the desired color.
2. Loop through each color using [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) (not the same as jQuery(selector).each.  This will loop through an object or an array (an object in this case), and run the associated function.  Each time it runs the function, it will pass the current key and value to the function.  So the first iteration, key = 'Strawberries' and value = '34a07e'.
3. For each color, change the css of all matching elements to the desired color.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
 var colors = {
  "Strawberries" : "#34a07e",
  "Apples" : "#3194b1",
  "Peaches" : "#e1a82a",
  "Bananas" : "#ff0b00"
 };

 $.each(colors, function (key, value) {
  $(":contains(" + key + ")").css('color', value);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="Fruits in basket Strawberries" href="#">Strawberries</a>

<a title="Fruits in basket Apples" href="#">Apples</a>

<a title="Fruits in basket Peaches" href="#">Peaches</a>

<a title="Fruits in basket Bananas" href="#">Bananas</a>
```

Comment: Hi Manishie, Thank you for responding to my post. I noticed you passed variables k,v to $.each function what do these variables represent ?

Comment: What I should have asked is how is it working? In other words, how does jQuery know to associate key with the specific word for example "Apples" and value with specific color "#3194b1"? Thanks again it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
function switchLinkColor (fruit, color) {
   switch(fruit){
      case Strawberries: 
         $("a:contains('"+fruit+"')").css("color", color);
         break;
      case Apples: 
         $("a:contains('"+fruit+"')").css("color", color);
         break;
      case Peaches: 
         $("a:contains('"+fruit+"')").css("color", color);
         break;
      case Bananas:    
         $("a:contains('"+fruit+"')").css("color", color);
         break; 
    }

}
switchLinkColor("Apples", "#ff0000");
```

But this obviousy isn't really much of an improvement ... Still too repetitive and limiting.

I'd suggest that a switch case might not be the best approach, since it's not very flexible or scalable.
You will need to add a new case every time you add a new fruit! Besides, if you're executing all of these to change every link, there's really no "conditional" that requires an `if/else` or `switch` in the first place.

**A function that takes 2 arguments:**

1. the word to match and
2. the new link color you want to change it to

http://jsfiddle.net/gexr574g/

```
function changeLinkColor (word, hexColor){
    $("a:contains("+word+")").css("color", hexColor);
}
```

Then you could either call this function individually to change one link at a time...

```
changeLinkColor("Strawberries", "#34a07e");
changeLinkColor("Apples", "#3194b1");
```

...Or you could pull the fruit name & desired color from a data source or object.
Then loop through each of them to change every one... Which I see now was just explained in a separate answer. Good work @manishie!

**More flexible alternative!**

Add a 3rd argument to the function above to change the matched element - a link, div, paragraph, etc...

http://jsfiddle.net/gexr574g/3/

```
function changeTextColor (element, word, hexColor){
        $(element+":contains("+word+")").css("color", hexColor);
}

//change all `a` tags containing "Kumquat"
changeTextColor("a", "Kumquat", "#dd33aa"); 

//changes the text color of any paragraph containing the word "fruit" 
changeTextColor("p", "fruit", "#33ffaa");
```